# Spring unable to load property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am referring to a property source in spring with @PropertySource annotation, however spring is able to find it only if the name of the property file is application.properties.

My property file is in src/main/resources.

Comment: What value is being assigned to the String? What IDE are you using? Where in resources is the property you are trying to load from? Can you update your question to show your @PropertySource annotation? I think that is where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set up your configuration to be able to handle more than just a single property source. There are many ways you can do this, however I recommend that you keep your properties configuration separate from your other configurations in order to modularize the duties. While you can also use the @Value annotation to load properties, you may want to consider autowiring the environment for the time being.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ // this takes in an array of property sources
@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties") // precede your property with classpath to find it in resources
})
public class MyConfiguration()
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env; 

    @Bean
    public String provideSomeString()
    {
        return env.getProperty("some.property.in.file"); // get the property from the property file
    }
}
```

Here is a quick way to load properties with the @Value annotation as well.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")
})
@Component
public class MyConfiguration()
{
    @Value("${some.property.in.file}") // get the property from the property file
    private String property;

    @Bean
    public String provideSomeString()
    {
        return property;
    }

    @Bean // this bean is required in order to pass properties into the @Value annotation, otherwise you will just get the literal string
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually using the Value annotation to get property values, but the values are getting loaded only when the PropertySource is application.properties